# How to make a 2-level depth type definition in a struct?

Tags: go, struct

Currently I have the following definition for my structs:

```
type WholeJson struct {
    Features []Temp
}

type Temp struct {
    Properties Human
}

type Human struct {
    Name  string
    Age   uint
}
```

Which is working when unmarshaling a JSON string into a variable of type `WholeJson`, which would have the following structure:

```
{
    "features":[
        {
            "properties": {
                "name": "John Doe",
                "age": 50
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Go Playground sample here: https://play.golang.org/p/3WTLxR0EZWP

But I don't know how to write it in a simpler way. It is obvious that not both `WholeJson` and `Temp` are necessary as far as using the information they will hold. The only reason I have `Temp` is because I simply don't know how to avoid defining it (and still have the program work).

Presumably the `Features` property of `WholeJson` would have an array to some `interface{}`, but I can't nail the syntax. And I'm assuming the code for reading the unmarshalled data (from the playground sample) will stay the same.

How would I "squash" those those two structs into one (the `Human` struct i'm assuming is okay if it stays on its own), and still have useful data in the end, where I could loop through the `features` key to go through all the data?

Comment: What you are looking for is anonymous struct. You can use https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ for json to go struct generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK to define a type for each level of the hierarchy and preferred when constructing values from Go code. The types do not need to be [exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).

Use anonymous types to eliminate the defined types:

```
var sourceData struct {
    Features []struct {
        Properties Human
    }
}

var jsonString string = `{
    "features":[
        {
            "properties": {
                "name": "John Doe",
                "age": 50
            }
        }
    ]
}`
json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &sourceData)
fmt.Println(sourceData.Features[0].Properties.Name)
```